# '\' wont close quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to parse through a string to look for all slashes in the string but cannot close out the parenthesis.

```
    for i in string:
          if i == '\':
                do_something
```

It wants to treat the \' as one character. Is there a way to nullify that?

Comment: If you want the `\ ` character, double it up. If you want the `'` character, double *that* up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash character with another backslash.

```
for i in string:
      if i == '\\':
            do_something
```